# Load CSV data in Mysql via phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a excel file like this:

```
      a
1 word1 : mean1
2 word2 : mean2
3 word3 : mean3
.
.
```

and I have saved this a cvs file. Can I import this cvs file to mysql with this table?

```
id   word   mean
1    word1  mean1
2    word2  mean2
```

I have tried `CSV using LOAD DATA` with `Fields terminated by :` and only ids imported.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a copy of your Excel file. In the copy:

- delete the row with the **a** in it.
- delete the column with the colons.
- insert a headings row, so that the
  spreadsheet looks like the table you
  want in MySQL.

Export the copy to CSV.

Create a database in phpMyAdmin.

Use these settings on the **Import** page of phpMyAdmin.

In the **Format of imported** file section, select CSV.

In the **Options section**, set the following:

- *Fields terminated by* **,** (after all, it
  is a CSV file with comma separated
  values)
- *Fields enclosed by* "
- *Column names in first row* **checked**

In the **File to import** section, browse for the file on your computer, wherever you saved it.

Click the **Go** button.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is a short PHP script, something like this:

```
<?php

$fp = fopen('path-to-csv.csv','r');

while ($row = fgetcsv($fp)) {

$sql = "INSERT INTO `table` (`col1`,`col2`) VALUES ('{$row[0]}','{$row[1]')";
mysql_query($sql);

}

?>
```

Comment: I want to inset data thet separeted with ',' in two colomn.

Answer (score 0):

use phpmyadmin

choose export as `Excel 2007 XLSX Workbook`

check the checkbox saying

```
Put fields names in the first row
```

Save as file. Thats all.